# Launching application with different Activities at different situations

Tags: android-activity, android

I am working on an application where I have to launch activity asking user to enter login and password to proceed further. The user will get option to save login/password. If user saves login and password, the application will not show login activity at next launch and instead should go directly to the main application screen.

I am thinking of starting application with Application class object and checking stored preferences to decide which activity is to launch. For some reason, application class is not launched, it may need some extra thing in manifest file.

Any suggestions what would be the best way to implement this kind of behaviour.

Thanks
Bsengar

Comment: Use a splash screen to display your logo or whatever while you check `SharedPreferences`. Make it your first `Activity` and if it passes go to the next `Activity`. If not then go to your login `Activity`

Comment: thanks codeMagic..looks good option

Comment: read stored info where you r storing it. If values are there just start home activity instead of login activity else start login act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions what would be the best way to implement this kind of behaviour

A splash screen is often used for this. Your first `Activity` (splash screen) can display your logo/and or play music or whatever while you check your data and decide which `Activity` to go to next like login or main `Activity`. This usually shouldn't be displayed very long (maybe less than a second or so unless doing network stuff such as authenticating/loading data).

> ...and checking stored preferences to decide which activity is to launch

This is often how people handle this. You can check `SharedPreferences` in your splash screen to decide which `Activity` to start. If the login is stored then go to main `Activity`. If not then go to your login `Activity`.

Make sure to call `finish()` in your splash screen so if the user presses the back `Button` from login or main `Activity` they will exit the app instead of going to the splash screen again, unless of course that's what you want.

[Good example of getting started with SharedPrefs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) in case you aren't familiar.

[Full Docs for SharedPrefs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application that does something very similar.  In my case, I use a "remember me flag" that allows the user to indicate that they want the application to save the login id and password.  If they elect this setting, the application will save the login information in preferences and pre-fill the login screen the next time the user launches the application.

Comment: thanks for reply. My case is a bit different. I dont want to show the screen at all, have to go to main app